# C Programming: Scanf in while loop only reads input once and then terminates

Tags: c, while-loop, char, character, scanf

I am new in C programming and I am currently learning about `while` loops. The problem I have is, that the `while` loop must continue until the user wishes to terminate the `while` loop. But when i run my code it seems that `scanf()` only once scans for input and the `while` loops terminates afterwards and I don't know why.

```
int main(void) {
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    char answer = 'y';
    while (answer == 'y') {
        printf("continue? (y/n): ");
        scanf("%c", &answer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is your intention with  `setbuf(stdout,NULL)`

Comment: Im a windows user. And there's a problem with the buffer in c when you use printf and scanf at the same time in windows. To make printf give an output instantly, you need to write fflush(stdout) everytime after every printf. If you write setbuf(stdout, NULL) at the beginning, you dont need to write fflush(stdout) after every printf.

Comment: yes it may be a problem in some environment but the way you have it probably won't actually work around all problems, shouldn't you try instead `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` - the mode flag is what changes how the stream behaves see e.g. comments here http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/168233/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consume the newline character.

Change

```
scanf("%c", &answer);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &answer);
```

Comment: I doubt that will give the behavior he wants. Consider if someone types `yes<enter>`.

Comment: Wow. as simple as a space character can make a difference. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I don't get you, if someone type `yes<enter>` instead of `y<enter>` the loop terminates, as is supposed.

Answer (score 0):

Every character other than `y` terminates the loop. If you hit `y<newline>`, the `y` will cause the loop to run one more time and then the newline will terminate the loop.

The basic problem is that you are reading one character when you actually want to read one line.